# android mediaplayer error on prepare()

Tags: android, media-player

here's the code I'm working on.... Ive already downloaded the file and it was successful.

```
try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(f.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e ("Fail", "File  not Available !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e ("Fail", "File  not Available !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e ("Fail", "File  not Available !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i ("Success !!", "File ready to be played !!");
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e ("Fail", "Fail to play");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e ("Fail", "Fail to play");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.i ("Success !!", "MediaPlayer is playing = " + mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
```

But it got error when I'm trying to set prepare();
Here's my LogCat :

```
07-20 10:40:12.387: INFO/ActivityManager(581): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.radio.streamingradio/.Tune_in }
07-20 10:40:14.148: INFO/ActivityManager(581): Displayed activity com.radio.streamingradio/.Tune_in: 1326 ms (total 1326 ms)
07-20 10:40:15.477: INFO/Success !(798): URL is available
07-20 10:40:16.047: INFO/Success !(798): Connected !
07-20 10:40:16.197: INFO/Success !(798): Stream Acquired !
07-20 10:40:16.217: INFO/Success !(798): Media will be saved to/data/data/com.radio.streamingradio/cache/media.m3u
07-20 10:40:16.227: INFO/Info(798): Downloading......
07-20 10:40:17.277: INFO/Info(798): Download complete !
07-20 10:40:17.667: INFO/Success !!(798): File ready to be played !!
07-20 10:40:17.703: ERROR/PlayerDriver(554): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
07-20 10:40:17.707: ERROR/MediaPlayer(798): error (1, -4)
07-20 10:40:17.707: ERROR/Fail(798): Fail to play
07-20 10:40:17.717: WARN/System.err(798): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-20 10:40:17.767: WARN/PlayerDriver(554): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
07-20 10:40:17.787: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-20 10:40:17.797: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.radio.streamingradio.M3UPlayer.playMedia(M3UPlayer.java:103)
07-20 10:40:17.797: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.radio.streamingradio.Tune_in.onClick(Tune_in.java:40)
07-20 10:40:17.807: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
07-20 10:40:17.822: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
07-20 10:40:17.837: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6504)
07-20 10:40:17.837: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
07-20 10:40:17.847: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.860: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.860: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.860: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.860: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.867: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-20 10:40:17.867: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1712)
07-20 10:40:17.867: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)
07-20 10:40:17.877: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)
07-20 10:40:17.887: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1696)
07-20 10:40:17.907: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
07-20 10:40:17.907: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 10:40:17.907: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 10:40:17.917: WARN/System.err(798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-20 10:40:17.917: WARN/System.err(798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 10:40:17.940: WARN/System.err(798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 10:40:17.987: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-20 10:40:17.987: WARN/System.err(798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-20 10:40:17.987: WARN/System.err(798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 10:40:17.987: ERROR/MediaPlayer(798): start called in state 0
07-20 10:40:17.987: ERROR/MediaPlayer(798): error (-38, 0)
07-20 10:40:17.997: INFO/Success !!(798): MediaPlayer is playing = false
07-20 10:40:18.074: ERROR/MediaPlayer(798): Error (-38,0)
```

Pls help... THX

Comment: Are you trying to play MP3 playlist (.m3u) file?

Comment: yeah...But, the sound isn't coming out

Answer (score 1):

Android does not support playback of MP3 playlist `(.m3u file`). M3U file is a text file containing URL to the Mp3  files in the list. However Android supports playback of MP3 files amongst other formats. Full list of supported file formats is present at [http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

To play MP3 playlist, one option is to download the M3U file without using MediaPlayer, parse it to get the URL to the MP3 file and then give media player the URL of the MP3 file.

Comment: I've tried your way, but inside the m3u file I got, there's no .mp3 extension file nor any URL of audio file....... what am I supposed to play ???

Comment: What does your M3U file contain? Does the content look similar to what is explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U

Comment: no, not like the file in wikipedia. my m3u file only contains http://cast.idvps.com:8000/djwirya. no audio file extension. But, when I use windows media player, it plays....no idea what's going on

Comment: I guess they have left out the extension. What happens when you try to play http://cast.idvps.com:8000/djwirya using Android media player. Plus can you find out what is the properties of file using Windows Media Player(Using File->Properties menu)?